# Gradient under a image

Tags: html, css

i want to make a gradient go under my wave effect so when you scroll down the wave fades away by using a gradient.

My CSS code:

```
section {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
```

}

```
section .wave:before {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 143px;
background: url(images/wave2.png);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.8;
animation: wave-reverse 15s linear infinite;
```

}

```
section .wave {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 143px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: url(images/wave2.png);
animation: wave 10s linear infinite;
```

}

```
section .wave:after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 143px;
background: url(images/wave2.png);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.6;
animation-delay: -5s;
animation: wave 15s linear infinite;
```

}

```
@keyframes wave {
0% {
    background-position: 0;
}

100% {
    background-position: 1360px;
}
```

}

```
@keyframes wave-reverse {
0% {
    background-position: 1360px;
}

100% {
    background-position: 0;
}
```

}

```
.waveGradient {
width: 100%;
top: 100px;
bottom: 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(#429bf4, transparent);
```

}

My HTML code for this:

```
<section>
<div class="wave">
    </div>
    <div class="waveafter"></div>
</section>
```

images:
this is what its like when you load up the page.
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxgoD.png)
Gradient goes under the wave image to make it look like it fades away.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeRkn.png)